# Failing to replace typo for NA for a list in R

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, na

I would like to replace this typo `"-"` for `NA` for a list of df's in R,

I am using the following code, however it throws me an error;

Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

**Code**

```
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){
  is.na(x) <- x == "-"
  x
})
```

**Console Output**

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, "-"), dates = seq(as.Date("2021/01/01"), 
                                                as.Date("2021/01/03"),
                                                by = "month"),
                  strings = c("hello how are you", "hey man", "-"))

df2 <- data.frame(b = c(3,4, "-"),
                  dates = seq(as.Date("2021/01/01"), 
                              as.Date("2021/01/03"),
                              by = "month"),
                  strings = c("hello how are you", "yoooo", "-")
                  )

df3 <- data.frame(c = c(5, "-", 7),
                  dates = seq(as.Date("2021/01/01"), 
                              as.Date("2021/01/03"),
                              by = "month"),
                  strings = c("hello how are you", "hello world", "-"))


df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be related to the different type i.e. `Date` class.

```
df_list[[1]]$dates == "-"
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
> unambiguous format

May be we can select only the `character` columns

```
df_list2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
      i1 <- sapply(x, is.character)
      x[i1] <- replace(x[i1], x[i1] == "-", NA)
     x
    })
```

-output

```
df_list2
#[[1]]
#     a      dates           strings
#1    1 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2    2 2021-01-01           hey man
#3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

#[[2]]
#     b      dates           strings
#1    3 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2    4 2021-01-01             yoooo
#3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

#[[3]]
#     c      dates           strings
#1    5 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2 <NA> 2021-01-01       hello world
#3    7 2021-01-01              <NA>
```

---

Or it can be also done by converting to `character` class, but that should be avoided

```
as.character(df_list[[1]]$dates) == "-"
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rapply` here. The `classes` argument let's you apply `f` only to columns of class character.

Similar to akrun's idea, maybe a bit more compact.

```
rapply(
  df_list,
  f = function(x) replace(x, x == "-", NA),
  classes = "character",
  how = "replace"
)
#[[1]]
#     a      dates           strings
#1    1 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2    2 2021-01-01           hey man
#3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

#[[2]]
#     b      dates           strings
#1    3 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2    4 2021-01-01             yoooo
#3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

#[[3]]
#     c      dates           strings
#1    5 2021-01-01 hello how are you
#2 <NA> 2021-01-01       hello world
#3    7 2021-01-01              <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.matrix` to convert all elements in the list to characters, i.e.,

```
> lapply(df_list, function(x) replace(x, as.matrix(x) == "-", NA))
[[1]]
     a      dates           strings
1    1 2021-01-01 hello how are you
2    2 2021-01-01           hey man
3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

[[2]]
     b      dates           strings
1    3 2021-01-01 hello how are you
2    4 2021-01-01             yoooo
3 <NA> 2021-01-01              <NA>

[[3]]
     c      dates           strings
1    5 2021-01-01 hello how are you
2 <NA> 2021-01-01       hello world
3    7 2021-01-01              <NA>
```